# Can we restrict openfile dialog control to not to show shortcuts(.lnk files) despite setting different filter

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, openfiledialog

I am using an openfiledialog control in c# to open ppt files by default.
But,despite setting the filter for the *.ppt,folder and programs shortcuts are also getting displayed which I want to avoid.

Isn't there some way to force the OpenFileDialog **NOT** to display shortcuts
like .lnk and .url files..

My code:

```
openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "*.ppt";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Powerpoint Presentations|*.ppt;*.pptx";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.DereferenceLinks = false;
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a file.";
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

Now,though my openfile dialog window filters the ppt files from all files but it also displays .lnk files which I want to avoid..
Please suggest the way to do so...

Comment: No repro at all.  Smells like a shell extension problem.

Comment: @Hans Passant What do u mean by 'shell extension'...!!